# Spring MVC: Custom DateFomratter not call by Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration, format

I am trying to use date formatter for displaying the formatted date in user front end. When i create the formatter and register the fomatter, the custom formatter not call by spring. Follwing is my fomatter code:

```
public class DateFormatter implements Formatter<Date>{

@Resource(name="messageSource")
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Override
public String print(Date date, Locale locale) {
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = createDateFormat(locale);
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

@Override
public Date parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = createDateFormat(locale);
    return dateFormat.parse(text);
}

private SimpleDateFormat createDateFormat(final Locale locale) {
    final String format = this.messageSource.getMessage("app.dateformat", null, locale);
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    return dateFormat;
}}
```

Following is configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
--------------------------
 @Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addFormatter(gatDateFormatter());
}

@Bean(name="dateFormatter")
public DateFormatter gatDateFormatter() {
    return new DateFormatter();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addFormatter(dateFormatter);
}

@Autowired
private DateFormatter dateFormatter;

@Bean
public DateFormatter dateFormatter() {
    return new DateFormatter();
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation on your code like how it solves the issue and why